# Add items to listbox in C# with thread

Tags: c#

I want to add some items to listbox with a thread or backgroundworker in C#. But when I call `addlist` function in a loop my program is not responding for a while. How can I fix that?

Here is my code:

```
   public delegate void addToList(string st);

   public void addlist(string st)
   {
        if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            listBox1.Invoke(new addToList(addlist), st);
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(st);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've got an unconditional call to `listBox1.Items.Add(st)` at the end of your method - get rid of that. If that doesn't help, please tell us what happens with the code you've got.

Comment: Looks like the O.P. deleted the extraneous `listBox1.Items.Add(st)` after Mr. Skeet commented.

Comment: Jon Skeet ; when I want run this code for 1000000 for example my program is not responding during this time

Comment: Is it Invoking? or just adding to the list box, break on both conditions and see, I think you will find it is outside the thread at this point.

Comment: Do you have your items stored in a List<T>?

Comment: @afshin Why are you adding a million items to a listbox?  That sounds like a nightmare for a user to use.  You should redesign the UI to not have so many items in a control rendered on a page at once.  Perhaps rely on pagination, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming with your `.InvokeRequired`/`Invoke(...)` code that you are using WinForms and not WPF.

`BackgroundWorker` will call the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events on the main thread (assuming you created the worker on that thread). If you are adding items to your `ListBox` on either one of these events, you should not require the `Invoke()`.

If you are going to be rapidly adding items to the `ListBox.Items` collection, I suggest you use `ListBox.BeginUpdate()` and `ListBox.EndUpdate()` which will temporarily suspend redrawing of the `ListBox` while you add items. This is useful when you are adding hundreds or thousands of items to the `ListBox` in mere seconds.

For example:

```
void ReloadListBox()
{
   listBox.BeginUpdate(); // Suspend redrawing
   listBox.Items.Clear(); // Remove all existing items first

   backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); // Asynchronous generate new items
}

void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // Report a new list item in e.UserState.

   var newItem = e.UserState;
   listBox.Items.Add(newItem);
}

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   // Alternatively, return a list of items in e.Result.

   var items = e.Result;
   listBox.Items.AddRange(items);

   listBox.EndUpdate(); // Resume redrawing and update
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this..

```
private delegate void Update();


public void addlist(string st)
 {
   listBox1.Invoke(new Update(() => listBox1.Items.Add(st)));  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really that sure that i understood your question, but try

```
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    //listBox1..... do whatever you want.
}));
```

Also read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this while I was using a thread and I have solved it with the following

1. First of all in the Form class constructor or in the Form_Load event make sure to set the control property like

> ListBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

2. add a delegate like this code

> delegate void setTextCallBack(String data);
> private void setText(String data) {
> if (this.ListBox1.InvokeRequired)
> {
> setTextCallBack d = new setTextCallBack(setText);
> this.Invoke(d, new object[] { data });
> }
> else {
> ListBox1.Items.Add(data);
> }
> }

and this worked for me
some answers I got while researching was to add the first step only but I'm not sure